# Throwing a RuntimeException causes the transaction to rollback, but Exception doesn't in a spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-boot, spring-data

In the following code throwing an `Exception` doesn't rollback the transaction, but throwing a `RuntimeException` does.

```
@Service
public class HelloService {    
    @Autowired
    protected CustomerRepository repository;
    @Transactional
    public void run() throws Exception {
        repository.save(new Customer("Jack", "Bauer"));
        throw new RuntimeException("Kabooom!!!"); //Transaction is rolled back. Database is empty :)
        //throw new Exception("Kabooom!!!"); //If this is used instead the records are inserted into the database. :(

    }
}
```

My repository:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {
}
```

Spring boot appliction.properties:

```
# DataSource settings: set here configurations for the database connection
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost/hobbadb
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password =
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver    
# Specify the DBMS
spring.jpa.database = MYSQL    
# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true    
# Hibernate settings are prefixed with spring.jpa.hibernate.*
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto= create-drop
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-attransactional-settings):

> Any RuntimeException triggers rollback, and any checked Exception does not.

You can override this behaviour by specifying `rollbackFor` or `rollbackForClassName` on the `@Transactional` annotation. See above docs for a full set of options.